# How do I manually test JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I'm trying to learn javascript by making a simple price checking website using the Best Buy products API.

How do I "run" the javascript? My form takes in a product ID number (the SKU) and sends it to validateSKU() on submit. The function processData(data) searches for the product using the SKU.

Nothing is happening when I test the site, and any help would be great; thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learn JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="bestBuyForm" name="bestBuyForm" onsubmit="validateSKU()">
    <input id="SKU" name="SKU" required="" type="text">
    <label for="SKU">SKU</label>

    <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
    <label for="email">Email</label>

    <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    function validateSKU() {
      var SKU = document.forms["bestBuyForm"]["SKU"].value;
      var bby = require('bestbuy')('process.env.BBY_API_KEY');
      var search = bby.products('sku=' + SKU);
      search.then(processData);
    }

    function processData(data) {
      if (!data.total) {
        console.log('No products found');
      } else {
        var product = data.products[0];
        console.log('Name:', product.name);
        console.log('Price:', product.salePrice);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: it is not the best way to learn javascript, its like "learning to drive on F1 track"

Comment: @ray No errors show up. When I click submit, the only thing that happens is that the page refreshes. If I put the javascript in a test.js file and make "var SKU = 1234567", and type "node test.js" in the console, the script runs as intended.

Comment: The first step debugging this is to add a `console.log('hello!')` to the `validateSKU` function and see if that fires correctly.

Comment: Your `onSubmit` handler should stop the form from submitting by taking an `event` argument and calling `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to see what does happen and read about the [console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console).

Try to bind `validateSKU` with HTML element addEventListener method. Also you should prevent default form behaviour which cause page reloading on submit. Call `event.preventDefault()`.

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/fuyutatuga/edit?html,console,output) code:

```
<html>
  <form id="someForm">
      ...
      <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
  </form>
  <script>
    function validateSKU(event) {
      console.log('IT works');
      event.preventDefault();
      // ...here your code
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('someForm');

    form.addEventListener('submit', validateSKU, false);
  </script>
</html>
```